# Should I wait or should I grab the existing opportunity?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, job-offer, human-resources

I applied for two companies and I and I thought I had received both jobs.
 Company A emailed me a job offer a day before Company B. It was basically just a plain job offer sheet stating all benefits etc, but the catch is, it does not guarantee the job. There's a disclaimer at the the end saying that it is not the official Job Offer but a "Pseudo Job Offer" (in my interpretation) where the job package is discussed.

The job offer stated in the end that the final job offer still depends on the final approval of the Owner of the company and the results of my medical. I agreed to the Job offer and emailed back and then HR and I exchanged a few calls and clarified a few things; so I was delighted since its a very big company. Now all I have to do is wait for the final approval and the medical exam has been scheduled.

A day after Company A made me an offer Company B called and also offered me a job (smaller company, nearer to where I live, and has higher pay). I did not say yes or no immediately because I am still waiting for my scheduled medical examination with Company A. Two weeks after Company A and Company B gave me their offers, Company A still does not have a concrete answer regarding the final approval and my medical exam sched; Company B on the other hand was cornering me to sign the Job offer sheet (since they waited for two weeks and they need to know if they need to move on and look for another candidate). So I signed the Job offer sheet of Company B, just to be sure that I have back up.

I am now asking for updates from Company A so that I can rescind from Company B as I don't want to be too unfair with them and lead them on. Their HR was replying at first and told me that the application is still with the owner and she hopes to get the approval at the end of the week. One full week has passed and I still did not get any update, I texted the HR but still didn't hear back. Should I wait for Company A or should I forget about their offer and go to Company B?

Company B is a smaller company than Company A but has higher pay (Don't get me wrong Company B is not a small company but any company will look small compared to Company A since its a very big company). Company A has more benefits though and is more stable; on the other hand, I could learn more from Company B. Company A is a 3 hour travel from where I live and Company B is just and hour away from home.

Is it normal to wait for that long? Should I be alarmed with Company A? I really don't like waiting... I have other offers and interview scheds and I hate stalling and leading other companies that I am on board.. I really want to be part of Company A though since it will definitely look good on my resume, but the travel is too far and they are making me really impatient. Usually, I will just chill and wait for the offer but I am dying to leave the current company that I work for right now, so the situation is making me extra impatient. I can not afford to lose the offer of Company B if Company A would not give me a definite response, because it would leave me with no choice but to stay with the current company that I am with and look for other jobs. Job hunting is very exhausting and challenging, I don't want to undergo the process again at the moment.

Comment: Have company B given you a formal contract of employment yet?

Comment: Company A is very large, yet require company owners approval for the job offer?  If this is not a senior management position, this doesn't make sense.  Seems like la strange form of job offer.

Comment: Its actually a senior mgt position :)

Comment: @TheMathemagician Company b gave me a job offer sheet stating the salary benefits etc.. with the approved signature of the President and me siging the acknowledged part.. I dont think its legally binding though.. Its just a plain JO sheet with no oblicon "lawyer" jargon stuff.. I dont want to burn bridges though.. If im going with Company A i want to tell Company B the soonest that I will not be joining the team... Its unfair for Company B since they have been very gracious to me..

Comment: I honestly thought those clauses were just legalese to cover their bases if they changed their mind.

Comment: Hi ImpatientApplicant and welcome to The Workplace.  As written this question doesn't fit our scope; we can't tell you which job to take.  (See the link in the "on hold" notice above.)  A question about how long it is usual to have to wait after signing the pseudo-offer *would* be on-topic.  So would a question asking how to extricate yourself from one of these offers.  And so would a question about how to speed things up with Company A, though I think we've had that question already (can't find at the moment but maybe somebody else can).

Comment: @TimSeguine i think so too.. but that does not give an applicant any comfort knowing that your employment is uncertain..

Comment: You're a senior manager and you need to ask us what to do? Jeez.

Comment: @ImpatientApplicant Where I live at least, you can always be let go before your starting date without any reason being given. Thus, contract or no, you have no 100% guarantee of a job.

Comment: @AakashM thats whey they have sites x threads like this.. we sometimes need other people's opinion regardless if you know what to do.. you need a sound board.. God bless you and more power.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was in this situation a few years ago.  I had an offer from my Company B the same day as the interview effectively.  I had been 'negotiating' with Company A for almost 2 weeks already.

I told Company A, they were taking too long and I was accepting another offer.  Not sure how they took it, since I never really communicated with them after that though.

It should be no surprise to Company A if you turn them down because they took too long.  It sounds like you are a prized prospect (2 offers) and company B knows that timing is important, whereas Company A does not.  Company B has their act together.  Stringing them along much longer and you may lose them and then A may end up dropping you too.

Comment: My fear exactly.. I do not want to cling on to Company A too long that I might miss my opportunity with Company B

Comment: And the way it sounds, you have the nicer bird in your hand as well.

Answer (score 3):

Big companies move slowly. Since you've accepted the offer from B (who have been quite patient with you - 2 weeks!) you should call A and tell them not to bother.

Company B looks great on paper but you want to name-drop Company A on your CV. That's fine. But that shouldn't matter too much really, what does matter is what you actually did during your employment. Consider two candidates: The first has worked for a giant conglomerate and spent their days being a lowly corporate pleb, dragging themselves from meeting to meeting. The other applicant has worked for a company you've never heard from, but actually helped them build and advance their business. This example is a bit extreme but you get the point.

It seems you'll be doing more important stuff at B going by salary alone (but that's not a good metric, only you know which role is better). If you keep playing games with B they might get the idea that you're not really into the job and you're using them as leverage to get somewhere else. You don't want that. It looks like Company A missed their chance.

Comment: what's keeping me from fully accepting Company B is that I dont want to be that sour person down the road and say that I missed my chance because I didnt wait for company A (a lot of people asprire to work there).. I on the other hand cant afford to not have back up plan though.. but I dont want to keep Company B waiting for too long and have their hopes up that ill join their team.. its unethical and unfair for them.. I really have to make up my mind asap..

Answer (score 1):

So you prefer A, but it's more important to you to not end up without a job?

If so, I'd set company A a deadline for providing a legally binding offer, and tell company B they will have my answer by that date (I'd talk to both companies to find a reasonable date).

That ensures that B's offer does not expire, and gives A a fair chance to top the offer. It does risk that you'll end up at B even though A would have offered (just because their administrative processes are slow does not necessarily mean it is a bad place to work for).

Comment: You should have done this when you got Offer B.  You have been stringing B along a long time given how quickly they made a solid offer to you.

Comment: Its really hard to make a decision... I want to work for Company A but its taking too long and I dont want to keep Company B waiting... I might miss my chance..